# How can I add a link to a Highcharts series name in the legend?

Tags: highcharts, hyperlink, legend

I have a multi-series column chart in Highcharts with three series ("Western", "Eastern", and "Central").  Clicking the label of a series in the legend shows or hides the series.  I'd like to add a little link at the end of each label with a link to download details about the underlying data for that series.

So a label would look like: **Western (details)**

I tried simply adding an `<A>` link to the "name" of the series, and the link appears, but clicking on it doesn't open the link.  Instead, it merely toggles the series display as before.  I guess the "onClick" event for the label itself supersedes the `<A>` behavior.

Is there any way, without hacking Highcharts or creating a whole custom legend, to make a link in a series label functional?  Maybe something with CSS to make the link jump out of its parent element?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is very good. You need to only call `e.stopPropagation()` after click on a link to prevent toggling series.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        name: 'Series name <a id="seriesDetails" href="https://www.google.pl/">Details</a>',
        ...
    }]
});

document.getElementById('seriesDetails').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // prevent redirect
    //e.preventDefault();
    console.log('click');
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kaLrmjd7/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.name